# UWP Is there any way to Print HTML content on a Windows 10 app?

Tags: printing, uwp, windows-10-universal

Is there any way to Print HTML content on a Windows 10 app?

i have res service return HTML content and i wanna to print the content from my Windows 10 app.

Comment: what do you mean to print? print via printer? or just render on screen? if you just want to render HTML on screen you can use WebView.NavigateToSring() and pass your HTML as string.

Comment: no i wanna print the content out via printer.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this @Anas Alathamneh?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found a solution, but I haven't tested it yet.

According to [MSDN - WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx)

> In addition, printing off-thread web content is not directly supported – **you should print an element with WebViewBrush fill instead**.

So you should use a visual element (e.g. a Rectangle) and then create a [WebViewBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush.aspx) to fill the visual element (e.g set Rectangle.Fill to the WebViewBrush instance).

Then print the the visual element.

To print visual element you can follow this sample

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing

Comment: did you ever try this? I am trying to do this but not having any luck